# Oath+Twitter IPhoneSDK

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth-2.0, mgtwitterengine

Does anyone know of a good example utilizing the twitter API and Oauth authentication for sending Twits iPhone SDK ...........

I got stuck @ sending the twits .........I can make a successful login to twitter Via Oauth+MGTwiiterEngine (Can check the credentials).

Now based on that session I want to know how to send twits..

Or either i can do this thing if i can get username & passsword when doing login...but how can i do that????

Help me in either of case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to tweet on some event or Button Action

```
        if(![_engine isAuthorized]){  
        UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  

        if (controller){  
            [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];  
        } 

    } 


    if(_engine){  
        [_engine sendUpdate:tweetContent];
    }
```